# If $x, y, z$ are independent random variables, are $ x-y, y-z, x-z$ also independent of each other?

Tags: probability, independence, correlation

If $x, y,  z $  are independent random variables, such as all following a uniform distribution between $0$ and $1$, are $x-y, y-z, ,x-z$ also independent of each other?

Comment: For the future. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance. This is the reason for which this post is so downvoted and there is the possibility that it will be closed in the future

Comment: @Marco Thank you for your advice. I realize that my expression was inappropriate this time, and I will make improvements in my future questions. Thank you again and I wish you a happy life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\mathbb{E}[(x-y)(y-z)]=-\mathbb{E}[y^2]-\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[y]-\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[z]+\mathbb{E}[y]\mathbb{E}[z]
$$
and similarly for the other products. So the r.v. are independent iif
$$
\mathbb{E}[y^2]=\left(\mathbb{E}[y]\right)^2
$$
i.e. iif the r.v. have zero variance. This is not the case for the uniform distribution